# pandas dataframe plot in a for loop, to generate separate images

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am working on a jupyter notebook where I have a for loop generating some time data which I'd like to plot into separate figures,

my code is this:

```
for test_year, solution in solutions:
    cur_year_data = <...calculate data...>
    title = str(test_year) + ' chart'
    plot = cur_year_data.plot(figsize=(25,25), title=title)
    figure = plot.get_figure()
    figure.savefig(title + '.pdf')
```

which generates a pdf file for each year, but all the data is inserted in the same figure, like shown

[image]

while I'd like each year to be on a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate figure instance within the `for` loop:

```
for test_year, solution in solutions:
    cur_year_data = <...calculate data...>

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,25))
    title = str(test_year) + ' chart'

    # pass ax here
    cur_year_data.plot(ax=ax, title=title)
    
    # use the figure instance
    fig.savefig(title + '.pdf')
```